# lookin' for a source to understand/learn EDI messages at spanish

Tags: edi, edifact

Well, does anybody know about an good source to learn about EDI messages? (by example the message 856 (ASN)). I would like a source in spanish language, but english it's acceptable too, something for dummys,blog,book/ebook,documentation,etc... step by step, we're probably starting to work with them in a few months, and we are really lost, we have documentation from our client, but if you know a good source a walk through, where to start, it will be welcome.

I just found the FrameworkEDI [www.edidev.co](http://www.edidev.co)

Any recommendation ? Somebody has worked with it ?

My regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm confused: you tagged edifact, but you reference an ANSI X12 document (856).  Which standard are you working with?

A to Z of EDI:

[http://www.amazon.com/EDI-Its-Role-E-Commerce/dp/1882419162/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1341941255&sr=8-2&keywords=EDI+A+to+Z](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1882419162)

You can usually get manuals on how to translate the data when you select a translator.   Perhaps you are looking for a commercial grade translator product that can help.  There are hundreds on the market.  Try this: http://liaison.com/products/transform/delta

Download EDI Notepad from Liaison (http://liaison.com/products/integrate/edi-notepad)
This tool will help you look at EDI data and understand it.

The EDIFACT wiki might be of some help, since it talks in terms of segments and elements: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EDIFACT

http://ediacademy.com/EdiQuiz.html

Comment: well oamm as you can see I'm just starting to learn, until I understand EDIFACT is another version or an specific use of EDI, am I right ?.

Well but I just ask to my superior and ANSI X12 documents are those we're gonna process (receive and send).

Comment: EDIFACT is an EDI standard predominantly used in Europe.  ANSI X12 is the most common standard here in the states.  The concepts are similar (envelopes, segments, elements), but the syntax is way different.  An 856 in X12 is the DESADV in EDIFACT.  Those are the transaction (document) identifiers.  In my mind, there's no benefit to studying EDIFACT if your project is X12.  Get the parter implementation guides and check out the 4 links i provided.